# segfaulting while playing with gcc wrap option

Tags: c, ld

Hello could anybody give me a hint what is going on here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void __wrap_exit(int code)
{
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    exit(5);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled: `gcc main.c -g -Wl,--wrap=exit`

I tried to debug the program and it prints:

```
Program  received signal    SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffde88 in ?? ()
(gdb) n
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

Before I tried similar experiment with open() and it worked nicely.
To avoid some funny compiler optimization around exit() I tried to compile with -O0 but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Men, it took me ages to discover what was going on.

My opinion is that sometimes gcc is too smart when not needed. In this case it handles `exit` as a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) instead of considering it a plain C function.

Here is my `test.c`:

```
extern void exit(int code);

void __wrap_exit(int code)
{
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    exit(5);
    return 0;
}
```

and these are the results:

```
$ gcc -fno-builtin -otest test.c -Wl,--wrap=exit
$ ./test; echo $?
0
$ gcc -fno-builtin -otest test.c
$ ./test; echo $?
5
```

Comment: yep this works. I tried extern void exit (int __status); (i.e. don't include stdlib), and other work-arounds but only this made the difference